# z-index and far separated elements

Tags: css, z-index

Basically what I am trying to do is have a div in the body with a fixed position float above everything. This works it is the next part where I have the problem, this is the code I use for it (in LESS)

```
.fadeIt{
    opacity:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    .transition (opacity .5s linear);
    z-index:-1;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    &.cover{
        z-index:101;
    }
    &.open{
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

This works and I have a click event on elements to toggle its visibility, however I want to pull the clicked elements over it regardless of their place in the DOM. Giving it an "accent" effect. Currently the fadeIt element is right by the end of the body tag, I feel this is "cleaner" but am open to changing it.

So what I want to see in the end is when I click on an element that triggers the visibility of the fadeIt element, that the clicked element will appear overtop of it in the same position it is in within the DOM.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly what you want, but if i do, I think for that you would need to reposition dynamically that element that was clicked, setting its position to absolute and using the top and left properties to position it exactly where it was and setting its z-index to at least 102.

Comment: Yea you seem to understand. That solution is correct but its a pain to go to that much depth, I want to see if anyone has an uber css hack that might help me avoid that solution.

Comment: actually now that i think about it, the z-index will work on any positioned element, so whatever elements you want to fire the event from, just position them right from the start with `position:relative;` (or whatever works with your layout) and a z-index of at least 102 and you should be good to go without having to  use any JS at all :)

Comment: I have been using that, however the element does not hover over top even with 999 z-index and position relative. I have tried a variety of methods and placements in the DOM, but it just does not want to align itself overtop.

Comment: well then i'll advise you to do a fiddle with what you have so that we can have a look.